# SQL Script to find Count the number of :username Occurrences of a String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores information whenever user make changes to the DB. I want to extract how many times the user make changes on the date on the application. The info is normally stored for each user in one row for example :

```
2019-06-15randomname1:YES I DID IT  2019-06-14randomname2:HHHHHHH  JJJJJJ   2019-06-14Urandomnamexxxxxx: COMMENT OF PEOPLE
```

What I want is to search :username to detect how many times the user has changed. In this instance. The answer suppose to be 3. How can I do it

```
DECLARE @logEntry           VARCHAR(4000);
SET @logEntry       =  ':' + (SELECT PERSON_NAME FROM P_PERSON WHERE PERSON = logged_person) 

SELECT 
       id
       ,value
       ,COUNT = (LEN(value) - LEN(REPLACE(value, @logEntry  , '')))/LEN(@logEntry)
FROM table
```

Will I use regular expression because for this particular example the answer will be 3 since we have 3.

I have decided to use :username I am having problem with Subquery returned more than 1 value :

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And I'm a bit confused.  There is no `datexxxxxxxxx` in your string, so `replace()` doesn't work.

Comment: I am using SQL, I was asking question if I could put wildcard search in that datexxxxxx. If I use date it will give me exact result. What I want is to search automatically for date

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan my question is to search any date in that format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, you want to count the occurrence of a date in a string

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(10) = '2019-01-01';

SELECT *, LEN(V) - (LEN(REPLACE(V, @D, '')) * 10) Occurrence
FROM (VALUES('A2019-01-01B2019-01-01C2019-01-01D2019-01-01E2019-01-01F2019-01-01'))T(V);
```

**Returns:**

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|                                 V                                  | Occurrence |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| A2019-01-01B2019-01-01C2019-01-01D2019-01-01E2019-01-01F2019-01-01 |          6 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Note that this will works only when the string doesn't contains a white spaces.

If you have a white spaces, then you need to remove them first as

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(10) = '2019-01-01';

SELECT *, LEN(REPLACE(V, ' ', '')) - (LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(V, ' ', ''), @D, '')) * 10) Occurrence
FROM (VALUES('A 2019-01-01 B 2019-01-01 C 2019-01-01 D 2019-01-01 E 2019-01-01 F 2019-01-01'))T(V);
```

---

You just changed your question, to search by a user name, but since the `':'` is fixed, and if you have 2016+ version you can do as

```
DECLARE @D VARCHAR(10) = 'UserName1';

SELECT *, 
      (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM STRING_SPLIT(V, ':') WHERE Value LIKE CONCAT('%', @D, '%'))
FROM (VALUES
      ('2019-06-15UserName1:YES I DID IT  2019-06-14UserName2:HHHHHHH  JJJJJJ   2019-06-14UserName1: COMMENT OF PEOPLE')
     ) T(V);
```

---

Finally, I'll recommend to re-think of that design, which is the real issue here, and read more about normalization.

---

*UPDATE:*

Here is how to count the user name with joining the two tables

```
SELECT *,
       (
         SELECT COUNT(1) 
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(Col, ':') 
         WHERE Value LIKE CONCAT('%', UserName)
       ) Cnt
FROM Users U JOIN Data D
ON D.Col LIKE CONCAT('%', U.UserName, '%');
```

**Returns:**

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----+
| UserName |                     Col                      | Cnt |
+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----+
| User1    | 2019-01-01User1:YES 2019-01-02User2:No       |   1 |
| User2    | 2019-01-01User1:YES 2019-01-02User2:No       |   1 |
| User1    | 2019-01-01User1:YES I 2019-01-02User1:No Way |   2 |
+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----+
```

See how it's working on **[live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=19fb1a07a659e1ba0620d8811ac0ddd5)**

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to search both : username ignoring date .

Comment: I think seaching the username since I can easily find usernae in the DB will help meI am having I am having problem with Subquery returned more than 1 value :This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or

Comment: @great77 You are looking to `COUNT()` the occurrence of a person name in a string?

Comment: Which version you're using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Sam. The username string is just sample. If you look at my edit code. I now have another table where username comes from.

Comment: @great77 What if the user type his username or others username?

Comment: the username  can be anybody it does not matter

Comment: @great77 Again, check the last updates. and click on the live demo to see how it's working.

Comment: The answer suppose to be 3 you are searching it based on distinct username, but I need it in distinct ID

Comment: @great77 Are you kidding me? First you update your question many times and change it. Second I just try to help you we are just volunteers here. Finally, the last updates counts the user name in the string, for each user name in the table users.

Comment: I am so sorry. I can modify it though.  Cheers

Comment: @great77 It's ok but, next time please if you have another question, please click on [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button, and you will get a lot of answers ;)

Comment: So you are searching for the string USERNAME concatenated with ":" colon.  What if you have two users named "FRED" and "ALFRED", and your string contains "ALFRED:".   This string also contains "FRED:".   Will you count 1 for both?

Comment: Man, where did you see a concatenation between the user name and `':'`? Are you trying to prove a point of view here? @DavidDubois. You have a demo there where you can test with those names.

Comment: @DavidDubois Have a nice day man. [Play with that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d627946a14e1ba4a557cc38573b6f8a).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend.  My point of view, as other have mentioned, is that this data structure is not suitable for this kind of analysis.  It's my nature to look at data structures and algorithms and find cases where they don't work as expected.   I'm hoping to help anyone who is depending on these realize that there are cases where it fails.  I do appreciate your efforts in volunteering to help people in these forums.

Comment: It's ok man, I just point you to the right way, and also share a fiddle to understand, and for the data structures, I agree with that. Anyway you also try to help as you can and that's great ;). Have a wonderful day @DavidDubois .

Comment: Maybe I should try out that fiddle thing in future answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a lousy data model and processing.  You should not be just adding substrings to a string.  You should be adding new rows to a table.  And, you should not be encoding information in a string.  You should be using columns for that.

My strongest suggestion is that you fix your data model and processing.

That said, you might be stuck with this situation.  THe simplest solution is just to look for

```
SELECT id, value,
       (LEN(REPLACE(value, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX:', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX:1') -
        LEN(value)
       ) as Num_Times
FROM Table;
```

Of course, this assumes that `'XXXXXXXXXXXXX:'` doesn't actually occur in the message.  If that is a possibility, see my original comment on the data structure.

Comment: I am searching for date format in the row that match the format yyyy-mm-d

Comment: I approached it wrong way. I will search based on the format :username the username is unique for individual for every particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do as you ask, but you seriously need to reconsider how you store your data.  What if instead of someone commenting "I did it", they entered "I did it on 2019-01-01"?

```
-- DateCount
-- Return number of occurances of ####-##-## where # is a digit
create function dbo.DateCount(@s nvarchar(max)) 
returns int as
begin
  declare @k int = 0 -- @k holds the count so far
  declare @i int = 1 -- index into string, start at first character
  while @i < len(@s)-9 -- keep checking until we get to the end
    begin
      if substring(@s,@i,10) like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
        set @k = @k + 1 -- increment count if these 10 characters match
      set @i = @i + 1 -- check the next character
    end
  return @k -- return the count
end
go
select dbo.DateCount(  '2019-06-15randomname1:YES I DID IT  2019-06-14random'
                     + 'name2:HHHHHHH  JJJJJJ   2019-06-14Urandomnamexxxxxx: '
                     + 'COMMENT OF PEOPLE'                                     )
-- Result is 3
```

If you're keen on using a set-based solution instead of a while loop, you can try this:

```
create function dbo.DateCount(@s nvarchar(max))
returns int as
begin
  declare @k int;
  with A as ( select 1 as I
              union all
              select I+1 as I from A where I<=len(@s)-9 )

  select @k=count(*) from A 
  where substring(@S,I,10) like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
  option (maxrecursion 0)

  return @k
end
```

But, in my performance tests, I find that the set-based solution takes 50% longer.

Comment: I see you have now decided to look for user name instead.  What if someone puts a user name or a colon into a comment?   Instead of entering "I did it", they enter "I am UserFred: I did it on 2019-01-01"?

Comment: I have changed my approach now. I am using :username

Comment: It will be  hard. I might changed the format to be ::#username. In this way it will be hard.Thanks

Comment: I won't use a `WHILE` loop when I can use a set based solution, cause it performs slowly.

Comment: @Sami.   I liked your suggestion of a set-based solution, but in my tests it takes 50% longer.  I'd like to see your solution that counts occurrences of ####-##-## within a string.